# How can I use a url string parameter when the url doesn't use /

Tags: javascript, html, url, query-string

How can I use a url string parameter when the url doesn't use `/`? I'm used to using `/:parameter_here`, but how can I use that variable syntax when using `?` and `&`?

**URL (Doesn't Work)**

```
www.test.com/users?status=ACCEPTED&party_id=:partyId
```

Comment: I'm confused at what you're asking.

Comment: `/:parameter_here` is express syntax IDK if you're getting confused with that...

Comment: If the URL does not end with `/users` then it's like `www.test.com?status=ACCEPTED&party_id=partyId`. I don't understand the question, either.

Answer (score 0):

`www.test.com/users/parameter_here?status=ACCEPTED&party_id=partyId`

parameter_here will be parameter_here

status will be ACCEPTED

and party_id will be partyId

You don't need the &, ? or = for parameters in the URL.